# CASE Error in MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that work in an INSERT statement but not as a stand alone, and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Here's the code that works:

```
declare @FY1 char(4)
set @FY1 = (DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(m,-2,GETDATE()) ))
declare @fy char(2)
set @fy = SUBSTRING(@fy1,3,2)
declare @MonthUnits char (2)
set @MonthUnits = datepart(mm, dateadd(mm, -2, getdate()))

create table #tmpJDEnbrunits (mcmcu char(12)
        , NbrUnits float
        , mcdl02 char(40))
insert into #tmpJDEnbrunits
select '000' + ltrim(MCMCU)
, CASE @MonthUnits 
WHEN  1 THEN GBAN01/100 -- January
WHEN  2 THEN GBAN02/100 -- February
WHEN  3 THEN GBAN03/100 -- March
WHEN  4 THEN GBAN04/100 -- April
WHEN  5 THEN GBAN05/100 -- May
WHEN  6 THEN GBAN06/100 -- June
WHEN  7 THEN GBAN07/100 -- July
WHEN  8 THEN GBAN08/100 -- August
WHEN  9 THEN GBAN09/100 -- September
WHEN 10 THEN GBAN10/100 -- October
WHEN 11 THEN GBAN11/100 -- November
WHEN 12 THEN GBAN12/100 -- December
  END
, mcdl02 
from [JDEPSQL1\JDEProd].JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F0902, 
[JDEPSQL1\JDEProd].JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F0006 
where GBMCU = MCMCU and 
GBFY = @fy and GBLT = 'AU' and
GBOBJ = '9900' and GBSUB = '006' and
MCSTYL in ('R') AND MCMCU<'         999' AND 
MCRP22<>'X'

select * from #tmpJDEnbrunits
where NbrUnits > 0
```

But when I try to run just the SELECT with the CASE to eliminate the temp table, like this:

```
declare @FY1 char(4)
set @FY1 = (DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(m,-2,GETDATE()) ))
declare @fy char(2)
set @fy = SUBSTRING(@fy1,3,2)
declare @MonthUnits char (2)
set @MonthUnits = datepart(mm, dateadd(mm, -2, getdate()))

select '000' + ltrim(MCMCU)
, CASE @MonthUnits 
    WHEN  1 THEN GBAN01/100 -- January
    WHEN  2 THEN GBAN02/100 -- February
    WHEN  3 THEN GBAN03/100 -- March
    WHEN  4 THEN GBAN04/100 -- April
    WHEN  5 THEN GBAN05/100 -- May
    WHEN  6 THEN GBAN06/100 -- June
    WHEN  7 THEN GBAN07/100 -- July
    WHEN  8 THEN GBAN08/100 -- August
    WHEN  9 THEN GBAN09/100 -- September
    WHEN 10 THEN GBAN10/100 -- October
    WHEN 11 THEN GBAN11/100 -- November
    WHEN 12 THEN GBAN12/100 -- December
  END
, mcdl02 
from [JDEPSQL1\JDEProd].JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F0902, 
[JDEPSQL1\JDEProd].JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F0006 
where GBMCU = MCMCU and 
GBFY = @fy and GBLT = 'AU' and
GBOBJ = '9900' and GBSUB = '006' and
MCSTYL in ('R') AND MCMCU<'         999' AND 
MCRP22<>'X'
```

I get the following errors:

```
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Qry1043'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Qry1016'.
Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.
```

The last one is especially odd because the CASE statement has no nesting. Any help will be appreciated, I've been Googling for an hour with no luck!

EDIT: It literally seems to think the WHENs are nested CASE statements. If I comment out any two of them it will run without errors.

Comment: What/where is `Qry1043`?

Comment: I assume you copy and pasted the `select` portion?  Is it possible it picked up some strange formatting or non-displayed character?

Comment: lc - I have no idea what 'Qry1043' and 'Qry1016' are, they don't appear anywhere in the code.

ngneema - the original code had the temp table and insert, I removed that part to run just the SELECT with the CASE.

Comment: Referencing any views?

Comment: The case is nested in the execution plan and it is that query with the nested case that gets sent to the linked server. More info [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42850/2103)

Comment: That would explain why it works in table creation vs in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Mikael, that is exactly right. I "solved" this with a klugey workaround - I split the query into two parts, one with the first 10 cases and one with the last two, and used UNION ALL. It's ugly but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using some strange auto conversion here or this is not your actual code.  If it is your code then do this so you compare strings to strings (not strings to numeric):

```
CASE @MonthUnits 
    WHEN '01' THEN GBAN01/100 -- January
    WHEN '02' THEN GBAN02/100 -- February
    WHEN '03' THEN GBAN03/100 -- March
    WHEN '04' THEN GBAN04/100 -- April
    WHEN '05' THEN GBAN05/100 -- May
    WHEN '06' THEN GBAN06/100 -- June
    WHEN '07' THEN GBAN07/100 -- July
    WHEN '08' THEN GBAN08/100 -- August
    WHEN '09' THEN GBAN09/100 -- September
    WHEN '10' THEN GBAN10/100 -- October
    WHEN '11' THEN GBAN11/100 -- November
    WHEN '12' THEN GBAN12/100 -- December
  END
```

Note also, if you really want an number you can use the builtin function MONTH

```
declare @MonthUnits int
set @MonthUnits = month(dateadd(mm, -2, getdate())
```

---

**aside**

I would expect to see that exact error message if your code actually looked like this:

```
CASE @MonthUnits 
    CASE WHEN '01' THEN GBAN01/100 -- January
    CASE WHEN '02' THEN GBAN02/100 -- February
    CASE WHEN '03' THEN GBAN03/100 -- March
    CASE WHEN '04' THEN GBAN04/100 -- April
    CASE WHEN '05' THEN GBAN05/100 -- May
    CASE WHEN '06' THEN GBAN06/100 -- June
    CASE WHEN '07' THEN GBAN07/100 -- July
    CASE WHEN '08' THEN GBAN08/100 -- August
    CASE WHEN '09' THEN GBAN09/100 -- September
    CASE WHEN '10' THEN GBAN10/100 -- October
    CASE WHEN '11' THEN GBAN11/100 -- November
    CASE WHEN '12' THEN GBAN12/100 -- December
  END
```

Here you have lots of case statements starting (nested) and no end statement for the case.

Comment: Question shows no nested `CASE` and OP specifically states there are no nested `CASE` statements.

Comment: I assure you, that is my actual code. I just tried using quotes as you suggested but got the same error. However, declaring @MonthUnits as int and using the MONTH function changed the error to "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'." The other errors went away.

Comment: Actually the syntax error was caused by a missing closing parenthesis, the original errors are still happening.

Comment: If I comment out two or more of the WHEN...THEN lines it runs fine. It really thinks those are nested CASE statements.

Comment: Yes, Viji, I still get the error with your code. I found the reason for the error: even though the local server knows that there is no nesting in my CASE statement, when the query goes out to the linked server **JDEPSQL1** the parser expands the statement, so the linked server will always see it as nested CASE statements. The workaround I used that worked was to split the query into two parts, one with the first 10 cases and another with the last two, and use UNION ALL. Once I did that the query ran without errors. It's annoyingly klugey but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
CASE 
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '1' THEN GBAN01/100 -- January
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '2' THEN GBAN02/100 -- February
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '3' THEN GBAN03/100 -- March
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '4' THEN GBAN04/100 -- April
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '5' THEN GBAN05/100 -- May
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '6' THEN GBAN06/100 -- June
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '7' THEN GBAN07/100 -- July
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '8' THEN GBAN08/100 -- August
    WHEN  @MonthUnits = '9' THEN GBAN09/100 -- September
    WHEN @MonthUnits = '10' THEN GBAN10/100 -- October
    WHEN @MonthUnits = '11' THEN GBAN11/100 -- November
    WHEN @MonthUnits = '12' THEN GBAN12/100 -- December
  END
```

You will not get "Case expressions may only be nested to level 10." error

Comment: we cannot declare variables inside a view. How does this work in a view? any idea?

Comment: do you have any column that has value matching @MonthUnits? , you can specify a column name in place of "@MonthUnits"